# Sort an ArrayList of Objects by last name, then first name

Tags: java

I have an arrayList of different types of players based on sports.  I need to sort the list of players in the arrayList by last name to start.  If 2 players have the same last name it needs to then sort those 2 players by the first name.
example: Format Lastname firstname

```
Williams Robert
Phillips Warren
Doe John
Phillips Mark
```

Output should be

```
Doe John
Phillips Mark
Phillips Warren
Williams Robert
```

What I have now only sorts by either the first or last. I have it by last atm in my code.

```
public static void sortPlayers(ArrayList playerList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < playerList.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < playerList.size(); j++) {
            Collections.sort(playerList, new Comparator() {

                public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                    PlayerStats p1 = (PlayerStats) o1;
                    PlayerStats p2 = (PlayerStats) o2;
                    return p1.getPlayerLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getPlayerLastName());
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change the comparator to:

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    PlayerStats p1 = (PlayerStats) o1;
    PlayerStats p2 = (PlayerStats) o2;
    int res =  p1.getPlayerLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getPlayerLastName());
    if (res != 0)
        return res;
    return p1.getPlayerFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getPlayerFirstName())
}
```

Comment: Also, get rid of the nested loops. Collections.sort does all the work for you

Answer (score 5):

Petar's answer is correct, just two remarks:

- Use `List` instead of `ArrayList` as method argument, as the interface is more general, and the method will work even if you change to another `List` type (like `LinkedList`... ) later
- Use generics to make your code more type safe.

An improved version:

```
//the place where you define the List
List<PlayerStats> playerList = new ArrayList<PlayerStats>();


public static void sortPlayers(List<PlayerStats> playerList) {
   Collections.sort(playerList, new Comparator<PlayerStats>() {
       public int compare(PlayerStats p1, PlayerStats p2) {
            int res =  p1.getPlayerLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getPlayerLastName());
            if (res != 0)
                return res;
            return p1.getPlayerFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getPlayerFirstName())
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using java8 there is easy way to do this:

```
public List<PlayerStats> getSortedPlayerList(List<PlayerStats> playerList) {
    return playerList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(PlayerStats::getPlayerLastName).thenComparing(PlayerStats::getPlayerFirstName)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    //requires java@8
    //class Person { String fName; String lName; int id}

    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.setfName("a");
    p1.setlName("x");
    list.add(p1 );

    Person p4 = new Person();
    p4.setfName("b");
    p4.setlName("z");
    list.add(p4);

    Person p3 = new Person();
    p3.setfName("a");
    p3.setlName("z");
    list.add(p3);

    Person p2 = new Person();
    p2.setfName("a");
    p2.setlName("y");
    list.add(p2);

    //sort by a single field
    Collections.sort(list, (o1,o2) ->  o1.getfName().compareTo(o2.getfName()));

    //sort by multiple cascading comparator.
    Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Person::getfName).thenComparing(Person::getlName));
    list.forEach( System.out::println);

    //output
    //Person [fName=a, lName=x, id=null]
    //Person [fName=a, lName=y, id=null]
    //Person [fName=a, lName=z, id=null]
    //Person [fName=b, lName=z, id=null]
```